# PHP code being removed by browser

Tags: php, json, compiler-errors

I'm working on a PHP project that allows a user to do a quick NY Times article search -- however, for some reason my PHP is not making it to the displayed page...chrome/firefox aren't commenting it out, the code just isn't there.  I've made a test helloworld.php and double checked my xampp setup, it all worked fine, so I really have no clue what to do, and my professor is equally stumped.

Here's the code so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NY Times Article Search</title>
    <link rel=”stylesheet” href=”css/bootstrap.css”  type=”text/css”/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src=”js/bootstrap.min.js”></script>

    <div class="container"> <h1><a href="index.php">NY Times Article Search</a></h1>               </div>

   <div class="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
              <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Recent Searches</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <div class="container">
        <?php
            require 'model/model.php';

            $data = search_article('romney');
            $json = json_decode($data);
            var_dump($json);
            print_r($json);
            $url = $json->web_url;
            $snippet = $json->snippet;
            $headline = $json->headline;

            echo $url;
        ?>
    </div>        

</body>
</html>
```

And here's model.php

```
<?php

function search_article($keyword){
    $base = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?";
    $format = "json";
    $api_key = "API_KEY";
    $url = $base . "q=" . $keyword . "&api-key=" . $api_key; 

    $data = @file_get_contents($url);
    return $data;
}
```

I tried to keep it really barebones so I could figure this out, but no luck...also, sorry if the code sucks, I'm not any good at web design.

Comment: PHP never reaches the browser

Comment: PHP is not a client side language and will not be visible at source. Also, you have displayed your API key... you might want to edit your comment above to remove that.

Comment: Whoops >.< and weird, I thought you could still look at the code via the f12 menu thing.

Comment: If your 'professor' is expecting PHP to show up in a browser, (s)he has no clue what (s)he is doing.

Comment: Yeah he hasn't been much help at all.

Answer (score 1):

First. Remove `@` from code for view errors. `file_get_contents($url);`

Maybe you have special chars in $keywords `If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you need to encode the URI with urlencode().`

Try

`$url = $base . "q=" . urlencode($keyword) . "&api-key=" . $api_key;`

Comment: Thanks, I'll put that in!